# if not for something

Tags: expressions

Source: [*Code: The Hidden Language of Computer Hardware and Software*](https://books.google.ru/books?id=gYlQAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) by Charles Petzold

Example:

> Electrons from the chemicals in the batteries might not so freely mingle with the electrons in the copper wires **if not for a simple fact**: all electrons, wherever they're found, are identical. There's nothing that distinguishes a copper electron from any other electron.

That's a very interesting phrase. Could you please explain to me what it really means and how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it seems odd is because a few words were left out, namely *it were*: what *“if not for”* really means is *“if **it were** not for”*.

So it is positing a hypothetical conjecture.

You may even see *“if not for”* written as *“were it not for”*.  It again simply means *“if it were not for”*.

Answer (score 1):

It is used to precede (come before) the reason the previous statement is not true or cannot be so. Think of it as "[This would be true/happen] if not for [this fact]."

Some simple (some admittedly contrived) examples:

"I would buy you lunch if not for the fact that I have no money."

"This glass would be perfect if not for the crack at the top."

"I would take a ride along the ocean road this afternoon if not for the fact that my motorcycle is out of fuel."